# OpenIddict migration from v2 to v3 rc1 - Login success, Authorize Failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, openid-connect, openiddict

I have tried to migration my project from v2 to v3 and I think i have updated everything, but for some reason i can login fine and i get an access_token returned, but this access_token fails to authorize a request.  Not sure why, but if someone can see anything obvious that would be great.  My application is a web Api with a angular2 web application for the client.

In v2 i was using JWT, but i understand that this is the default in v3 so i may have some code that needs to removed for this to work.

To restrict a controllers methods or a single method, i am using `[Authorize]` attribute.

Extension method to be called in Startup.cs for adding Authentication, done to keep Startup.cs file from getting to big and keeps things in one place

```
/// <summary>
/// Add authentication
/// </summary>
/// <param name="services"></param>
/// <param name="appSettings"></param>
public static void AddAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, AppSettings appSettings)
{
    // appSettings.ApiUrl = "http://localhost:5000"
    // appSettings.WebsiteUrl = "http://localhost:4200"

    // the default value for AllowuserNameCharacters is "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+"
    // here we have just added some additional characters
    services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options => { options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters += "'&"; })
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // Configure Identity to use the same JWT claims as OpenIddict instead
    // of the legacy WS-Federation claims it uses by default (ClaimTypes),
    // which saves you from doing the mapping in your authorization controller.
    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = Claims.Name;
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = Claims.Subject;
        options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = Claims.Role;
    });

    // return unauthorized message instead of url
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });

    // configure all tokens generated from aspnet to expire in 3 days (create password, forget password etc)
    services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options => options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3));

    // Authentication
    var authenticationBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
        .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Authority = appSettings.ApiUrl;
            cfg.Audience = appSettings.ApiUrl;
            cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            cfg.SaveToken = true;
        });

    // OpenIddict
    services.AddOpenIddict()
        .AddCore(options =>
        {
            options.UseEntityFramework(e => e.UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>());
        })
        .AddServer(options =>
        {
            // For token lifetimes look at the below link
            // https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/wiki/Configuration-and-options

            // Enable the authorization, logout, token endpoints.
            options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
                   .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/connect/logout")
                   .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token");

            // Note: the Mvc.Client sample only uses the code flow and the password flow, but you
            // can enable the other flows if you need to support implicit or client credentials.
            options.AllowPasswordFlow()
                   .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

            // Mark the "email", "profile" and "roles" scopes as supported scopes.
            options.RegisterScopes(Scopes.Email,
                                   Scopes.Profile,
                                   Scopes.OpenId,
                                   Scopes.OfflineAccess,
                                   Scopes.Roles);

            // code to allow requests without client_id
            options.AcceptAnonymousClients();

            options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
                   .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

            // Register the ASP.NET Core MVC binder used by OpenIddict.
            // Note: if you don't call this method, you won't be able to
            // bind OpenIdConnectRequest or OpenIdConnectResponse parameters.
            options.UseAspNetCore()
                   .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                   .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
                   .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                   .DisableTransportSecurityRequirement();  // Never use https because we use load balancer
        })
        .AddValidation(options =>
        {
            // Import the configuration from the local OpenIddict server instance.
            options.UseLocalServer();

            // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
            options.UseAspNetCore();
        });
}
```

Startup.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Configure services
/// </summary>
/// <param name="services"></param>
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // application settings
    var appSettings = new AppSettings();
    Configuration.Bind(appSettings);

    // mvc
    services.AddMvc(appSettings);

    // identity / saml etc
    services.AddAuthentication(appSettings);
}

/// <summary>
/// Configure application
/// </summary>
/// <param name="applicationBuilder"></param>
/// <param name="webHostEnvironment"></param>
/// <param name="loggerFactory"></param>
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // get current appSettings and output to logger
    var appSettings = applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<AppSettings>();
    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(appSettings.ApiUrl);
    logger.LogInformation(string.Format("{0}\n{1}", appSettings.Environment, appSettings.Data.DefaultConnection.ConnectionString));

    // environment
    webHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName = appSettings.Environment;

    // CORS
    applicationBuilder.UseCors("Default");

    // static files in root
    applicationBuilder.UseStaticFiles();

    // routing
    applicationBuilder.UseRouting();

    // comment this out and you get an error saying 
    // InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.External
    applicationBuilder.UseAuthentication();

    // for authorization headers
    applicationBuilder.UseAuthorization();

    // response caching
    applicationBuilder.UseResponseCaching();

    // routes
    applicationBuilder.UseEndpoints(options =>
    {
        // default goes to Home, and angular will deal with client side routing     
        options.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index" });
    });
}
```

I have updated my AuthorizationController.cs as well

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles authorization requests
/// </summary>
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class AuthorizationController : Controller
{
    private IOptions<IdentityOptions> _identityOptions;
    private OpenIddictApplicationManager<OpenIddictEntityFrameworkApplication> _applicationManager;
    private SignInManager<MyUser> _signInManager;
    private UserManager<MyUser> _userManager;
    private AppSettings _appSettings;
    private IEncryptionService _encryptionService;

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new authorization controller
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identityOptions"></param>
    /// <param name="applicationManager"></param>
    /// <param name="signInManager"></param>
    /// <param name="userManager"></param>
    /// <param name="appSettings"></param>
    /// <param name="encryptionService"></param>
    public AuthorizationController(
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> identityOptions,
        OpenIddictApplicationManager<OpenIddictEntityFrameworkApplication> applicationManager,
        SignInManager<MyUser> signInManager, UserManager<MyUser> userManager,
        AppSettings appSettings, IEncryptionService encryptionService)
    {
        _identityOptions = identityOptions;
        _applicationManager = applicationManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _appSettings = appSettings;
        _encryptionService = encryptionService;
    }

    // Note: to support interactive flows like the code flow,
    // you must provide your own authorization endpoint action:

    /// <summary>
    /// Authorize an openId request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectRequest"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Authorize, HttpGet, Route("~/connect/authorize")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authorize()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest() ??
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The OpenID Connect request cannot be retrieved.");

        // Retrieve the application details from the database.
        var application = await _applicationManager.FindByClientIdAsync(request.ClientId, new System.Threading.CancellationToken());

        if (application == null)
        {
            return Forbid(
                authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                properties: new AuthenticationProperties(
                    new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = Errors.InvalidClient,
                        [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] = "Details concerning the calling client application cannot be found in the database"
                    }
                )
            );
        }

        // Flow the request_id to allow OpenIddict to restore
        // the original authorization request from the cache.
        return View(new AuthorizeViewModel
        {
            ApplicationName = application.DisplayName,
            RequestId = request.RequestId,
            Scope = request.Scope
        });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Accept an openId request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Authorize, HttpPost("~/connect/authorize/accept"), ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Accept()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest() ??
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The OpenID Connect request cannot be retrieved.");

        // Retrieve the profile of the logged in user
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return Forbid(
                authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                properties: new AuthenticationProperties(
                    new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = Errors.ServerError,
                        [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] = "An internal error has occurred"
                    }
                )
            );
        }

        // create a new principal
        var principal = await CreatePrincipalAsync(request, user);

        // returning a SignInResult will ask OpenIddict to issue the appropriate access/identity tokens.
        return SignIn(principal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deny an openId request
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Authorize, HttpPost("~/connect/authorize/deny"), ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Deny()
    {
        // Notify OpenIddict that the authorization grant has been denied by the resource owner
        // to redirect the user agent to the client application using the appropriate response_mode.
        return Forbid(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logout
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost("~/connect/logout")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        // Ask ASP.NET Core Identity to delete the local and external cookies created
        // when the user agent is redirected from the external identity provider
        // after a successful authentication flow (e.g Google or Facebook).
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();

        // Returning a SignOutResult will ask OpenIddict to redirect the user agent
        // to the post_logout_redirect_uri specified by the client application.
        return SignOut(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    // Note: to support non-interactive flows like password,
    // you must provide your own token endpoint action:

    /// <summary>
    /// Exchange request for valid openId token
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpPost("~/connect/token")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Exchange()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest() ??
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The OpenID Connect request cannot be retrieved.");

        if (request.IsPasswordGrantType())
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Username);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return Forbid(
                    authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    properties: new AuthenticationProperties(
                        new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = Errors.InvalidGrant,
                            [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] = "The username/password couple is invalid"
                        }
                    )
                );
            }

            // Ensure the password is valid.
            if (!await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, request.Password))
            {
                if (_userManager.SupportsUserLockout)
                {
                    await _userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user);
                }

                return Forbid(
                    authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    properties: new AuthenticationProperties(
                        new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = Errors.InvalidGrant,
                            [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] = "The username/password couple is invalid"
                        }
                    )
                );
            }

            if (_userManager.SupportsUserLockout)
            {
                await _userManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user);
            }

            // create a new principal
            var principal = await CreatePrincipalAsync(request, user);

            return SignIn(principal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
        else if (request.IsRefreshTokenGrantType())
        {
            // Retrieve the claims principal stored in the authorization code/refresh token.
            var info = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            // Retrieve the user profile corresponding to the refresh token
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(info.Principal);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return Forbid(
                    authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    properties: new AuthenticationProperties(
                        new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = Errors.InvalidGrant,
                            [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] = "The refresh token is no longer valid"
                        }
                    )
                );
            }

            // Ensure the user is still allowed to sign in
            if (!await _signInManager.CanSignInAsync(user))
            {
                return Forbid(
                    authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    properties: new AuthenticationProperties(
                        new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = Errors.InvalidGrant,
                            [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] = "The user is no longer allowed to sign in"
                        }
                    )
                );
            }

            // create a new principal
            var principal = await CreatePrincipalAsync(request, user);

            return SignIn(principal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException("The specified grant type is not implemented");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a principal based on the openId request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request"></param>
    /// <param name="user"></param>
    /// <param name="properties"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreatePrincipalAsync(OpenIddictRequest request, MyUser user, AuthenticationProperties properties = null)
    {
        // Create a new ClaimsPrincipal containing the claims that
        // will be used to create an id_token, a token or a code.
        var principal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);

        if (!request.IsRefreshTokenGrantType())
        {
            // Set the list of scopes granted to the client application.
            // Note: the offline_access scope must be granted
            // to allow OpenIddict to return a refresh token.
            principal.SetScopes(new[]
            {
            Scopes.OpenId,
            Scopes.Email,
            Scopes.Profile,
            Scopes.OfflineAccess,
            Scopes.Roles
            }.Intersect(request.GetScopes()));
        }

        // Set resource
        principal.SetResources(new string[] { _appSettings.ApiUrl });

        // Note: by default, claims are NOT automatically included in the access and identity tokens.
        // To allow OpenIddict to serialize them, you must attach them a destination, that specifies
        // whether they should be included in access tokens, in identity tokens or in both.
        foreach (var claim in principal.Claims)
        {
            claim.SetDestinations(GetDestinations(claim, principal));
        }

        return principal;
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> GetDestinations(Claim claim, ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        // Note: by default, claims are NOT automatically included in the access and identity tokens.
        // To allow OpenIddict to serialize them, you must attach them a destination, that specifies
        // whether they should be included in access tokens, in identity tokens or in both.

        switch (claim.Type)
        {
            case Claims.Name:
                yield return Destinations.AccessToken;

                if (principal.HasScope(Scopes.Profile))
                    yield return Destinations.IdentityToken;

                yield break;

            case Claims.Email:
                yield return Destinations.AccessToken;

                if (principal.HasScope(Scopes.Email))
                    yield return Destinations.IdentityToken;

                yield break;

            case Claims.Role:
                yield return Destinations.AccessToken;

                if (principal.HasScope(Scopes.Roles))
                    yield return Destinations.IdentityToken;

                yield break;

            // Never include the security stamp in the access and identity tokens, as it's a secret value.
            case "AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp": yield break;

            default:
                yield return Destinations.AccessToken;
                yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

Also here is my applicationDbContext

```
/// <summary>
/// Application context to hold our openIddict entities
/// </summary>
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext, IApplicationDbContext
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create context with connection string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
    public ApplicationDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When creating models
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modelBuilder"></param>
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.UseOpenIddict();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Authorizations
    /// </summary>
    public virtual DbSet<OpenIddictEntityFrameworkAuthorization> Authorization { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Applications
    /// </summary>
    public virtual DbSet<OpenIddictEntityFrameworkApplication> Application { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tokens
    /// </summary>
    public virtual DbSet<OpenIddictEntityFrameworkToken> Token { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Scopes
    /// </summary>
    public virtual DbSet<OpenIddictEntityFrameworkScope> Scope { get; set; }
}
```

As i said, i am getting a token returned, like below

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUCIsImVuYyI6IkEyNTZDQkMtSFM1MTIiLCJraWQiOiI5NDVDNjFERjcyRUU1OUNDNUNFQzQ0NzJCRDE0MDg4NDEyNTAyRjM3IiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.TxmA-Lv60Lwvr5eXdu2fgG95Bx4AUoPvp5XniqSYbBgmpDrVXCUpSjnEv7tWQ5QLPjks6TAy8hGAGfgQPFB1xDM05mZyu2WDPBsoEQ2VtxuabaPhj-uK2KjnWEccjS-n-YAY7OlSDFXrmiDsFCOf3jaPGZ43gUCPyTVl_WVE_KBGVXa19RDZFf9Ger-TsHY3evYbsUchOKMco-CD2IGt6Xg6DttxFcKF3SUPwMXhn6AGdkNesGVIoVSeDd_CnM3MyHtJIbGbkRkmwpMWsbwaWGI38itUJ0XeUqn45B_GsZfaZllytuMHbuqt1GgL0gdOaCfBUxaqy7AaYsY9UKlaEw.LS4FnIOCRESdeo1c5K2_5Q.Ic8fssDScEu7lAomL8d_7JZMVho5hLphg269UIETZui7DUB2gund7YCtGq7imdnDtN-wsEoZaLHJ4UQSJrpuIMCN2pW69J9kKcx-UT1e2Ma-JNj2G5CtxwRf_bszRRsgWC1ia85LU5TPsUFvhd_wDxyUax2GKowb0FVl8EFRoFdZF40h06LaofxDzD2BFdwSYaHaDm3icVNZ0CRpYCoZq-MK_c3Fl98l57zjZl1CNscs1w0trApMDvQ7UeFcez3zelN24H6TCaXqTRP3lixMiv9Rtm3Kqkv67HEUAFD-vXIMyWQTo28oJMMAQz9zQeTp88JsfI4Pv7euUECEkwK7Fe5rbxhD4oicNNa_wmRo2vsjrpm4C7mmRKH2u3cX2CCTwahOsVHxu4kO3zliWmniW-krEAAsaW6BjoWqJiGN3ydoiHLIv3muM78jt85KzKxMIFsalpdf2F9Z8neQBglhzxZQFp9JiEecczxao6Y03WuFNX98kZh8Zr4D21CM_m634u3mf5-Gz-frVlSgnMrE9vgCG2eETI3fOnObf9pQ1XWpK7I9SE0AZvc2PciaKO4H7mKDqXuXFrzdiz6Tx9G9MMkXXbuKsuslZJ6q9wlE3xOl9mzd6shN9GvfSTQNrFoV-PS62xhnfCFKQDfYLzWF1fhQbq_RECp6IVJN960jaMAGIZ0yzIbRInIkbhdFEIbl__h9AYo6FfcZgYv4tfw-iB_unezgHCIPpbBPC0eRMiZh1wqpfwpiJ8zjvcXJXXCfSlu13KlBWD9tHVEHh6aHE258hGdFzApA-MTCkjHwMRjVgmv_-Ed-xwk0hjBpRhiZv-0kNwKI72YJVgZMX9CMpFBg2CO5z5hHSlc0pO9pc5ovuCZ_dYYRiqqcIDUJ5Wl6dDt1JCPI084C4yssC7MC4e94OtvfRtrI096qMI34qrLWi-jn7UOMnWMUunNepQLwQ07DK-ubXsS-m0xvSxPYxtE6XM6QebmvCcXj__vELGscDu8mWmvP1Y0L9SoSpWlErHvlCPpkfVeMnkdP74cKTYgpXSQcGduqcdfU86leI9oUYgnrcPwvMgUq3jwgHGWn_0d4Bo8CsChWatYWmSNKN88h3WfASSl6SyqeVbSSYvIp-0HBGxGOwODgO-YsOlOgeKmm8oSIhnELVNMVEY1uiUZpJ9DGfrUUXKMw7aIz6LK_zH_HxlMiBam0fxgAQwRyYlO0AFmuxFO62KEHFEjdDSEO9pcUP03_RNqDfAX-IAV_EoFT7CwVpOZMUvFLo78S4xkq2ss3CFbkA3J4ioud88T5SUfslnsZmY1dJYtW4HhlGF7SKVMN6GSwckz1YhyaxqlQpMbMRFA0uCbkM6u41K0-_toRQejKDX5juqFwqK8.m0bmPYOuAYYdc6WfjDWP2UneysP1G3FqwlmOzWOrTnM",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjcwMzJBRUJBQjc4NkNCM0ExRkI3Nzk1NjdDQTRGRjU1ODg3OTFCNDEiLCJ4NXQiOiJjREt1dXJlR3l6b2Z0M2xXZktUX1ZZaDVHMEUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwibmFtZSI6InBvd2VydXNlckBtZWFzdXJlMmltcHJvdmUuY29tIiwib2lfYXVfaWQiOiIxMDJjZTE0NC02NzkyLTRlYzAtOTlhNy0xZDBlMzdmNzkyZTYiLCJhdF9oYXNoIjoiV3BibExxNFdNR2dwdHdGVVVSMktRdyIsIm9pX3Rrbl9pZCI6IjQyMzBlYmJkLWUyNzItNDJlZS1iOTZiLTQ1ZGJmMTJlZWJmMiIsImV4cCI6MTYwNjQ3NzgzOSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwLyIsImlhdCI6MTYwNjQ3NjYzOX0.WZkB63ZfZuJfigNVabPegu-B8TvMeS1DmgRQJS151XGR08Pw-fcCldb35oM7ZW9oQenj7059BAZMI1EveHWNVWOEFpabebi7TccGRoR1YKqWSNWTBDwyQgGMyehVmze_TPgsSjAJA0y1f_xtF3-ImfVx5Tzlcjg4XAmAhV3MRd-fEobdGk5540uto5hZJ7ieHrV_7U_FF4NgVT5nSw92bkFNjUokmNgMBpDWelZUEXmsb3MFGDMnQkP0oTGXeIcy0nuuIKpr1Liza_cvv1JfICQnSUKw_u3zdqSbsbXtzGg9GfunEhXf1zSF5dxfbNpr2E4bsnIxGJ-mOYxBsOQDJA",
  "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUCIsImVuYyI6IkEyNTZDQkMtSFM1MTIiLCJraWQiOiI5NDVDNjFERjcyRUU1OUNDNUNFQzQ0NzJCRDE0MDg4NDEyNTAyRjM3IiwidHlwIjoib2lfcmVmdCtqd3QifQ.E5xUDcqMK15spCgqoM8YrOCn_32wBX_X_XsG_f1nKOR-TcDI2AKi07vX62uMmbO1bgclGSGNynEUTuPt7KATf9UHXwpytXAK3_BnLxQLz7NbYIlfrja9t5z3gCRIGOZ-5gHbHcU6RdJrDpC73_V7CXYIfkVhfWeeS30_3GtLa-BUu4Nlr9YL7K22KdR0LJQsK6SXLMKobsj6PLrrywHnClaw6dG_O_SDezC5M_eIo_ErdHFqUBwWYhUHyntijJ9ekH4A2SiY0LGaQD6QyvmUNPC7E-LtLVO78saJYAgGW-CkQbwTBF7b_vOoEr_mPrFnpytwLnIvxSQCFVjclH-vzA.RGNxh09nh1RWb6XU6jNZSg.VRwdO_5UrB7tqaMHXwt6qZN8VucSlNXnBNoBxcvisDvjWhBOlhrJxEidGQPBeiIpbrYrWQXyPfSgFrmZAlqYcF-3cXTl0W-xR4oW1ZqRf95eMs-YTA9-bR6n8P2pV7WeYky7wkwa-i3Vs9rzasYjK18LTU6v71xMNVN2K0Z2HRgTXxPg3U4HUgkVQpZp4qetyhozdOhGBV37igAHSZHFUSYg-dlstz3DtEX7IXvi7GQbM_fLKVlDLWYZOtX1yH366C9TIjZbxGP3h-qPqfKKDNP-IhD_x2IpymmiKllfhfLKb62JQzy_ci-ICXGvs0z_ZLZirmzVSEotqrcKmwe1rlqRXbymP8llIXe3AzjLonN3I_35bLeqZz1KQE93pkLOpJGAJuhJ4dc8a7wJ5kxTAs9_CCvb6UBvhRxInUyZ9PQq026RaYJvN9i--x8JxAAtH58h9Y5zgm_M4kFbEoGgZshyGZ8QSQrp4JpPrGeW9ElvkyEmrGvEpm6zmy_Y6tEF3lXFfrGJL6FPGD5_q8m9lGQ162OCmZMGg2Sy46Hne0SPv04TpM43F-m82BTzXxGRbpvOoNye7Pl9dKbdOBno1WEmaesL-R-W_8qogNszW5c-gbhQTUjcQ1J5yuVL4r29qN9xhVDPKqxPYPzInCr30m8SH41NI6WusFVJbNoqVs43wymGfQwuDfJacVCIfuT1Lx2VMdVl3nvCAGOnEwiUDufjqMaA-Nh-Row4QIwTHMGwfzxbFkQjRfwq_NjVU0LZlVDX2BgSETw2ak3KpgAGoeDlVVwmXuQpbvZ3wRHVh4a3k3_JVGf1dOiHbXVcWx984-EARKmW6gLjIhe2t5tzIJ9NQqBrdBrCvMmQXWfBiP00-YH31yDfYRF9tNZoojnkcrkOewHFUsEcFuayBzP5ySR6RgGVVE_zkEXTnBXxeiynzfJn0D3XthpRPosLJTJz91tdmvo6CxPWuaaZoUlXq_EXqFrGCb09f11Hs_mKu7T7pHMbJioTAvj1Jy8jzduMU3Rth-w0A8Md2gdeKmoCXW51lvpuyFsP4R8AdthhXGUbAk6rNJXdkaUkRyygYU8ZQWI2WCyroDnBRpEIaBtjYT1Uf4zXyTUZ3jicKe5Rjr08tmgAQd_3pNu1Wb2dBQgvcoqnwXcnLvoMTp0yk7Osae94Pqh_Oyz45kz_oS_7fR6WvZm-avBPYLmW92eQWiMG6glxPPe_Vnq9ghwjYjS4KEvyFaDqusDWmxBEDwEzLgBTF3p0R2saedTbwpG4Epcey_T18KEuklAWbCwz-fvV3ip-_wGUNe6cuAOeyuXcUHm18Le0knZt6xNS_a8cxMz9RAEpBs3a-tOWQLrVELXxnNY03NL2szkNQuDUzY9JRtTxqngxcPpHVk058dRG1rwFZqiI4-6_yL03X_fbXsIR0ItBig9surYyB_crwyH3C6OZTnGgwxLKUU9qY0LNTzR0gatrrT1l8NrorLAvODzQqhrqqClHgZkVoQXANvz3mNZWIpxjCkOgDkH-YOaaR3egnwLVMk_clo3-gC76UQ-5T-NnZ7MJTv2twFBhUKHABEJsT9a3nR7ra2CbHFzJFNvRRCPHAGOVAY-y-Ek0xZn8mvd3Fvw4wlej4EdQvlnFUcaIH4Cl0MZD9G9t2W3A96KLRZctVfGK6W1yM846DWHwSfeTj3ZPN_6bYDqbWHoXrQxe5BGi9aN8PXfL1Bu9W5jhQpgrvTRvnjhYqwN24ta9r6BbrMzBL3cszf56dG3Ko6aA8gDwUmDSjyNVhk76sdoW.1xLMuQf7NjeYjAXDL5BUxaoFSR0EECEzPh7XxkE8Hj4"
}
```

Here is the token being passed successfully, but Unauthorized is returned, as you can see the next call fails as well.
[image]

Any help much appreciated

Comment: For the record, this question has been answered on GitHub: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/1182.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but just post my solution in case anyone has the same issue.

Just specificy the schema for the Authorize attribute:

`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`